# jQuery to add two divs after UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wanting to add two divs after my UL via jQuery. How can I do this?

My UL is:

```
<ul class="linkList navigationLinks enabled" id="globalNav">
    <li class="navigationGroup" id="globalNavItem1">
              <a href="#><span>New</span></a>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

The divs I would like to add after the UL are:

```
<div id="left-primenav-bg"></div>
<div id="right-primenav-bg"></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something? I don't mean to be rude, but this is not a code-for-me site...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/after

Answer (score 1):

If the elements already exist and only need to be moved:

```
jQuery('#left-primenav-bg, #right-primenav-bg').insertAfter('#globalNav');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4safk104/)

If not, use jQuery to create them on the spot:

`jQuery('<div id="left-primenav-bg"></div><div id="right-primenav-bg"></div>')
    .insertAfter('#globalNav');`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4safk104/1/)

In both jsfiddles I've added content to the divs for clarity reasons. In the first I've added the existing elements into a hidden div to show they actually get moved out of that div.

Also, check the jQuery documentation on the insertAfter method: http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be

```
$("#globalNav").after('<div id="left-primenav-bg"></div><div id="right-primenav-bg"></div>')
```

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/after/